# In Hibernate: is it possible to mix Annotations and XML configuration for an Entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, annotations, xml-configuration

So, is possible to mix both configurations instead of use only one of those?

All I want is to keep all the configuration by Annotations and read the table by a XML.

Is it possible?

Thanks a lot.

Edit:
How will be the hbm.xml file? I have this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="MyData" table="MyTable" >
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And don´t compile the dtd.

Comment: This post tells that you can do it. Have you tried? https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=931958&view=previous

Comment: Yes, now I know is possible, but I don´t know how to fill my xml config file only with the table name.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Hibernate docs (latest)

> Note that you can mix the legacy hbm.xml use and the annotation
>   approach. The resource element can be either an hbm file or an EJB3
>   XML deployment descriptor. The distinction is transparent for your
>   configuration process.
>
> You can mix annotated persistent classes and classic hbm.cfg.xml
>   declarations with the same SessionFactory. You can however not declare
>   a class several times (whether annotated or through hbm.xml). You
>   cannot mix configuration strategies (hbm vs annotations) in an entity
>   hierarchy either.
>
> To ease the migration process from hbm files to annotations, the
>   configuration mechanism detects the mapping duplication between
>   annotations and hbm files. HBM files are then prioritized over
>   annotated metadata on a class to class basis. You can change the
>   priority using hibernate.mapping.precedence property. The default is
>   `hbm, class` and changing it to `class, hbm` will prioritize the annotated
>   classes over hbm files when a conflict occurs.