# Hibernate: Migrating from mapping to annotations - is it possible to mix hbm and annotation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations, hibernate-mapping

I'm currently migrating my project from Hibernate HBM Mappings to Annotations.
Everything was easy as far as i dealt with small classes.
But I have same huge classes and i try to mix both mapping and annotations for this class. I read that this was possible by using the hibernate property "hibernate.mapping.precedence" and setting it to "class, hbm" instead of "hbm, class". (see: [In Hibernate: is it possible to mix Annotations and XML configuration for an Entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643166/in-hibernate-is-it-possible-to-mix-annotations-and-xml-configuration-for-an-ent))

For example I have the following Document class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="DOCUMENT")
public class Document  {
   @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
   private String description;
}
```

and the following Document.hbm.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" 
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">    
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Document" table="DOCUMENT" >
    <id name="id" column="DOCUMENT_ID" type="long" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In my hibernate.cfg.xml file I put:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.mapping.precedence">class, hbm</property>
<mapping class="Document"/>
<mapping resource="Document.hbm.xml"/>
```

My problem is that:
- if I put "class, hbm" for the precedence then I have ONLY my annotations in class Document
- if I put "hbm, class" then I have ONLY my mappings in the hbm ressource

Does anyone knwo if there is a way to have both Annotations and HBM mappings ?

Thanks

Kamran

PS: I use : Hibernate 4.1.4 and Spring Framework 3.1.1

Comment: How to solved it ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't mix them for the same class. At the end of [section 1.2 of hibernate annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#setup-configuration):

*You can mix annotated persistent classes and classic hbm.cfg.xml declarations with the same SessionFactory. **You can however not declare a class several times** (whether annotated or through hbm.xml). You cannot mix configuration strategies (hbm vs annotations) in an entity hierarchy either.*

*To ease the migration process from hbm files to annotations, the configuration mechanism detects the mapping duplication between annotations and hbm files. HBM files are then prioritized over annotated metadata **on a class to class basis**. You can change the priority using hibernate.mapping.precedence property. The default is hbm, class, changing it to class, hbm will prioritize the annotated classes over hbm files when a conflict occurs.*

Using annotations and hbm files is declaring a class two times. Therefore, one will be prioritized over the other in a class to class basis (class to class basis means that for each class, only the hbm file or the annotations are used).