org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on references an unknown entity: Y with XML configuration
I can see similar topics but with annotations @Entity.
I have a similar problem but with xml configuration.
I am building sessionFactory this way:
configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
ServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

            try {
                LOGGER.info("Creating session factory");
                sessionFactory = configuration
                                .buildSessionFactory(registry);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy( registry );
            }

and during deployment I am getting an error:
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on Document.modifiedBy references an unknown entity: domain.user.CommonUser
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1598)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1521)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1422)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)

Indeed I don't have entity CommonUser because CommonUser is class implementing User interface.
public class CommonUser extends HibernatePersistentObject implements Serializable, User 

I have configuration via xmls, not annotation so in hibernate.cfg.xml I have:
<mapping resource="path/User.hbm.xml"/>

and in User.hbm.xml of course I have:
<hibernate-mapping schema="bba">
    <class name="path.CommonUser" table="users" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="userId" column="USER_ID" type="int">
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">sequence</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

Not sure if this matters but in Document (annotation) class I have:
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
private CommonUser sig;
private int order;
@ManyToOne
private CommonUser modifiedBy;

Why hibernate don't know CommonUser if I have this defined in hibernate.cfg.xml:     <mapping resource="path/User.hbm.xml"/>

I think you did it for simplification, but hibernate misses domain.user.CommonUser and you define path.CommonUser, that's irritating for me...
A real match i'd like better

yes, I did for simplification path is domain.user.CommonUser. I see that if I moved from xml configuration to annotations for CommonUser then I don't see this error anymore but it is shouting about different class which is also configured in xml. I am not sure how to do it, now the only way which I can see is moving to annotations.

I read something about that and that you can configure what configuration is leading: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643166/in-hibernate-is-it-possible-to-mix-annotations-and-xml-configuration-for-an-ent

Thanks @Turo. Yes, I guess it's doable but I can't make it work. I will try to migrate everything to annotation, I think.
